# Can we use $E=mc^2$ as the internal energy of gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, mass-energy, gas

I was studying the fluid equation in cosmology and saw that when they derive this equation from the first law of thermodynamics, they use $E=mc^2$ as the internal energy (of the universe maybe). Is this exactly the same as applying thermodynamics to a gas in a piston? If so, can we also  use $E=mc^2$ for the internal energy in a gas?

I'm not sure if $E^2=p^2c^2+ m^2c^4$ would be a better choice for the internal energy as it's not used in the derivation of the cosmological fluid equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosmology describes galaxies as an ideal gas, in which galaxies are considered as particles. Not quite the same as a piston, because there is no pressure term. The velocities of galaxies relative to comoving coordinates are neglected, because they are small compared to the speed of light. For a gas there are thermal motions to consider, and the $E=mc^2$ term can be neglected, because local dynamics concerns energy differences. It is absorbed into the arbitrary constant in energy.

Comment: Yes, The vacuum can be simulated also as an ideal gas, right ?